# Forum is removed but still being visited by Googlebot

Tags: wordpress, googlebot, 404

I've removed Simple Machine Forum (SMF) from my blog and from Google's index . I've even removed the sub-directory /forum from my blog techwayz.com and blocked it through robots.txt file. Unfortunately, it is still being visited by Googlebot. Every time Google visits the forum, I receive a 404 error alerts in webmaster tools. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that there are links to it on external websites and Google is following the links from those websites and then hitting the 404 page.

In Webmaster Tools Crawl Errors, click the 404 link and check the 'Linked From' tab to see if any one is still linking to it.